# How can I loop through created html cards + loop through a JS object to pull data from?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I'm trying to loop through some HTML 'cards' I made, they have images on them and when clicked will act as a button to open a pop up with further information.

In retrospect I'm trying to loop through each card that's stored in a variable via QuerySelectAll and for each card I want specific inner HTML to be displayed that's pulled from an object depending on which card / image is clicked on.

Sorry this is my first question here and I've been teaching myself web development for past 5-6 months so might not have the lingo 100% correct yet! :)

Some HTML code snippets:

```html
<div class="item-container">
  <h4>Rats</h4>
  <div class="cards" id="rat">
    <img src="./SVG/Rat.svg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item-container">
  <h4>Wasps</h4>
  <div class="cards" id="wasps">
    <img src="./SVG/Wasp.svg">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Model -->

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <h1></h1><br>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I store each class item '.cards' in a variable via:

```
let cardsBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.cards');
```

And have 2 variables to access the modal data:

```
let modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

let modalContent = document.querySelector('.modal-content');
```

I can quite easily achieve this by writing the code out multiple times but it looks rather messy and I'm sure it can be optimized! Couple examples are:

```
cardsBtn[0].onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalContent.childNodes[1].innerHTML = pestInfo[0].name;
  modalContent.childNodes[6].innerHTML = pestInfo[0].info;
}
cardsBtn[1].onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalContent.childNodes[1].innerHTML = pestInfo[1].name;
  modalContent.childNodes[6].innerHTML = pestInfo[1].info;
}
```

But I have 12 objects in total to do this for so you can imagine the code get's quite messy!

I'm exploring the Array.ForEach() approach but seem to be hitting a roadblock with it.

I can run this:

```
    cardsBtn.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (index = element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalContent.firstElementChild.innerHTML = pestInfo[0].name;
      modalContent.lastElementChild.innerHTML = pestInfo[0].info;
        })
      } 
    })
```

Which works, but I can't seem to then add an else if statement afterwards and I believe there must be a way to use ForEach() on pestInfo after just for a For loop and display the correct pestInfo depending on the index number.

I've tried pestInfo[index] but sadly that does not work.

I basically need to find a way to say if it's the rat card then show the rat object info and if it's the wasp card then show the show object info

Any ideas or suggestions?

Many thanks,

Cregory

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delegate: wrap your itemcontainers in an container and use addEventListener on that container.
2. Use IDs in the modal instead of `childNodes[1]` and `childNodes[6]`- it makes it really hard to read and remember what it is

Have a study of this

1. I generate the cards from the object using map and template literals
2. I delegate from the container
3. I use a class to show and hide the modal
4. I use memorable variable names/IDs

```js
const pestInfo = [
{ "name":"wasp", "text":"Flying pest", "img":"https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/211-2112215_transparent-hornet-png-wasp-transparent-png-download.png", "info":"Yellow stripes"},
{ "name":"rat", "text":"Running pest", "img":"https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/14-149302_rat-transparent-background-hd-png-download.png", "info": "Hairy animal"},
]

const pestContainer = document.getElementById("pestContainer");

pestContainer.innerHTML = pestInfo
  .map(({name,text,img, info},i) => `<div class="cards" data-idx="${i}">
    <h4 class="name">${name}</h4>
    <p><img src="${img}"/><p class="text">${text}</p>
  </div>`).join("");

const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const modalTitle = document.getElementById("modalTitle");
const modalText =  document.getElementById("modalText");
pestContainer.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const idx = e.target.closest("div").dataset.idx;
  modal.classList.remove("hide");
  modalTitle.innerHTML = pestInfo[idx].name;
  modalText.innerHTML = pestInfo[idx].info;
})
modal.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click",function() { modal.classList.add("hide") });
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }

#pestContainer img { height:100px}
```

```html
<div id="pestContainer"></div>
  <!-- Model -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h1 id="modalTitle"></h1><br>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="modalText"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I usually do use ID's this is the first time I've used Child Nodes and not really sure why I did as this makes much more sense, I may of been overthinking it!

Forgot about template literals and thought I could use something with .maps, thank you for the example, I'm going to try and incorporate this into my code and see if I can get something working.

Thank you again!